# Sharepoint 2013 Workflow Split String

Tags: string, sharepoint, split, sharepoint-2013, workflow

I am trying to create an email that contains a list of requested items all on their own line. The problems is in that each of these items are stored in a separate list and are outputted as a single line of text and in share point 2013 there appears to be no split function. Does any one know of an easy way to go through a string (each item will be separated by a #) and output each one on it's own line. This only needs to happen inside the email and does not need to be saved elsewhere (although this could be a solution). Please see screenshots below for more details. The only solutions I could find online look like they either only work in SP2011 or require parsing through via iterators.

-----Here is what the current email looks like-----:
[image]

-----Here is the template I am using-----:
[image]

-----And here is what it looks like when creating a new request-----:
[image]

Again the goal is to simply put each requested item into its own line. The items that are available for request are saved in a separate workflow.

Any help is greatly appreciated and if you require any additional info please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to set the 'Return field as' of requested items field to Lookup Values in your email workflow. I succeed in having the lookup values without a #.
[Lookup Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWIAc.png)